# Take always a different random element in range

Tags: java, arrays, random

I need to select two different integers that belong to a certain range `[min, max]`.

**Example**: `rds = 3`, `min = 0`, `max = 9`. If the first random element is `r1 = 6`, then `r2` must be different from `6` and `r3` must be different from `r1` and `r2`.

I thought of building an array containing all the numbers belonging to `[min, max]`: `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`.

I select a random number between `0` and `9` with return `ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, 10)` and then I swap `r1` and the last element of the array.
To find `r2` I apply the random function from `0` to the penultimate position in the array, and so on.

This is the code:

```
public void takeRandomXposition(int rds, int[] positions) { 
    int k = positions.length;
    int min = 0;
    int max = k - 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < rds; i++) {
        int r = random(positions[min], positions[max - i]);
        swapPositions(positions, r, max - i);
    }
}

public int random(int min, int max) {
    return ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(min, max + 1);
}

public void swapPositions(int[] positions, int index, int last) {
    int indexA = positions[index];
    int lastA = positions[last];
    positions[index] = lastA;
    positions[last] = indexA;
}
```

This method works for the first steps, but not anymore.
The problem is that the elements in the array are moved and mixed, but I try the random number in a range.
I don't know how to explain, I give an example in which the method doesn't work.

```
positions: [ 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ]
rds = 3
k = 10
min = 0
max = 9

    i = 0
    search r in range [0, 9]
    r = 5
    positions: [ 0 1 2 3 4 9 6 7 8 5 ]

    i = 1
    search r in range [0, 8]
    r = 3
    positions: [ 0 1 2 8 4 9 6 7 3 5 ]

    i = 2
    search r in range [0, 7]
    r = 5
    positions: [ 0 1 2 8 4 7 6 9 3 5 ]
```

In addition there is also a problem when `r = 0`:

```
positions: [ 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ]
rds = 3
k = 10
min = 0
max = 9

    i = 0
    search r in range [0, 9]
    r = 0
    positions: [ 9 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 0 ]

    i = 1
    search r in range [9, 8]
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bound must be greater than origin
```

So, I don't want to find a random number in a range `[min, max]` but a random number in the contents of an array.

Thanks.

Comment: why you don't make a method which represent a number (index) of array in specific range (to control indexOutOfBoundException) with a simple mathematics formula ?!

Comment: @MR1 Sorry, I didìnt understand what you mean.

Comment: as i understood your question, you want access to the content of an array randomly, to do this you need access to specific element of array, so with specify that method you can access to a random element of array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store your generated random numbers in a list and keep generating until you find one which is not in the list.

```
LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();
final int min = 0;
final int max = 10;

while(list.size() < max) // Condition to not keep iterating forever
{
    do 
    {
        int random = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(min, max + 1);

    } while (list.contains(random));

    list.add(random);
}
```

You can also use an approach with arrays, as you were trying to do

```
int min = 0;
int max = 10;
int array[] = new int[max + 1];

int filledArray = 0;

while(filledArray < max + 1) // Condition to not keep iterating forever
{
    do 
    {
        int random = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(min, max + 1);

    } while (array[random] == 1);

    array[random] = 1;
    filledArray++;
}
```

EDIT: Im not completly sure if this is what you are looking for. What I understood is that you want to find random numbers in a given range without getting twice the same random number

Comment: Yes, you understood. I think is fine the way you suggested, but I'm afraid it perform poorly.
If for example I have to generate 5 random numbers in the range [0, 9], to create the ultimate number, the method should be quite a bit inside the while loop. I'm right?

Comment: @marielle not really. In the first approach (with the list), replace the outer `while` condition with `list.size() < 5`. When the loop ends, in the list you will have 5 different random numbers within the given range. With the array is almost the same, you only have to either add a list where you stored the generated numbers, or iterate over the array to check which positons has 1

Comment: Thanks, Nadir, I used you first approach.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may want to shuffle. You can make it easy by wrapping the whole process in a class.

```
class NonRepeatingRandomNumberGenerator {

    List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList();
    int index = 0;

    public NonRepeatingRandomNumberGenerator(int min, int max) {
        for (int i = min; i <= max; i++) {
            numbers.add(i);
        }

        Collections.shuffle(numbers);
    }

    public int getNext() {
        // If your range has 5 numbers and you want 7 you will have to repeat at some point
        if (index == numbers.size()) {
            index = 0;
            Collections.shuffle(numbers);
        }

        return numbers.get(index++);
    }
}


// Usage
NonRepeatingRandomNumberGenerator rng = new NonRepeatingRandomNumberGenerator(10, 42);
rng.getNext();
rng.getNext();
rng.getNext();
```